# How do I calculate the total of all the prices in a list ? such as this one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
expenses =['Grocery-200.00', 'Gas-100.78', \
           'Rent-1200.00', 'Water-23.34', \
        'Vacation-356.89', 'Phone-123.00']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split on the "-", cast to float and sum:

```py
sum([float(x.split("-")[1]) for x in expenses])
```

Comment: You can pass a generator expression rather than a list comprehension in a case like this. :)